# How to trigger code for Automatic Categorisation of Outlook 2010 incoming email by Regex and VB

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to develop a custom rule for Outlook 2010 to filter the email. The expected result using regex shall be:

> Subject : `[ABC]`      --> create inbox folder `ABC`

I have turned on the macro at the Trust Center. When it comes to the implementation and testing, this flow cannot be triggered.

Would you please tell me how to trigger the macro?

Here is my code written in VBA

```
Public Enum Actions
    ACT_DELIVER = 0
    ACT_DELETE = 1
    ACT_QUARANTINE = 2
End Enum


Sub MyNiftyFilter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Matches, Match
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    Dim mc As system.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    Dim GoodRegEx As New RegExp
    GoodRegEx.IgnoreCase = True

    ' assume mail is good'
    Dim Message As String: Message = ""
    Dim GroupName As String: GroupName = ""
    Dim Action As Actions: Action = ACT_DELIVER

    ' SPAM TEST: Illegal word in subject'
    regex.Pattern = "(v\|agra|erection|penis|boner|pharmacy|painkiller|vicodin|valium|adderol|sex med|pills|pilules|viagra|cialis|levitra|rolex|diploma)"
    GoodRegEx.Pattern = "(([\w-\s]*)\s*)"

    If Action = ACT_DELIVER Then
        If regex.test(Item.Subject) Then
            Action = ACT_QUARANTINE
            Set Matches = regex.Execute(Item.Subject)
            Message = "SPAM: Subject contains restricted word(s): " & JoinMatches(Matches, ",")
        ElseIf GoodRegEx.test(Item.Subject) Then
            Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
            For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
                results(i) = mc(i).Value
                If i = 0 Then
                    GroupName = results(i)
                    Set MailDest = ns.Folders(GroupName)
                    Item.Move MailDest
                End If
            Next

        End If
    End If

    ' other tests'

    Select Case Action
        Case Actions.ACT_QUARANTINE
            Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
            Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

            Dim junk As Outlook.Folder
            Set junk = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)

            Item.Subject = "SPAM: " & Item.Subject
            If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                Item.HTMLBody = "<h2>" & Message & "</h2>" & Item.HTMLBody
            Else
                Item.Body = Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Item.Body
            End If

            Item.Save
            Item.Move junk

        Case Actions.ACT_DELETE
            ' similar to above, but grab Deleted Items folder as destination of move'

        Case Actions.ACT_DELIVER
            ' do nothing'
    End Select
End Sub


Private Function JoinMatches(Matches, Delimeter)
    Dim RVal: RVal = ""

    For Each Match In Matches
        If Len(RVal) <> 0 Then
            RVal = RVal & ", " & Match.Value
        Else
            RVal = RVal & Match.Value
        End If
    Next

    JoinMatches = RVal
End Function


Private Sub Application_NewMail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    ' your code here
    MyNiftyFilter (Item)
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you try to run `Sub MyNiftyFilter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)`? https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code in following method - this method is triggered, when the new mail is coming

Do not hardtyping method, but choose from declaration list, see picture :

```
 Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    ' your code here
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have got procedure error. Please see me edited code

Comment: Where is the error? Sorry but cannot see? which line and what error? Thanks

Comment: Thought this approach works, it will stop working with the time or multiple mails.. been there.

Comment: I see this error Iser defined type not defined at this code of line：Dim mc As system.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection

Comment: do u have "System" checked in your references list?

Comment: No, how to add 'System' and create the reference ?

Comment: click Tools>References, and check System

Comment: @Peter NewMail is triggered but there is no way to identify the item that triggered it. NewMailEx could be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

*[Work with Items.ItemAdd event (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.ItemAdd)*

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
        MyNiftyFilter Items
    End If
End Sub
```

> *Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.*

Comment: Is  my configuration for turning on macro no problem?

Comment: @RajuyourPepe create a self signing certificate  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956E9CC8-BBF6-4365-8BFA-98505ECD1C01

Comment: just can't create my certificate on my Window Explorer as I am using windows 10